# Did Apple drop the keyword 'Server' from the Mac Mini category?

Tags: mac, mac-mini

With the new line up of Mac Minis we can have up to 16 GB of RAM, and 3.0 GHz CPU, and therefore they can act as a server. But why did Apple just drop the 'Server' keyword from the Mac Mini category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They haven't announced a Server version, it may come later.
Only Apple can know that.

The 'Server' version was not the same as the regular version, it had 2 HDs, no optical drive & had OS X Server installed, rather than the desktop OS.

From [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i7-2.3-late-2012-server-specs.html)

> For all practical purposes, the "Server" configuration is identical to its non-server contemporary, but ships with dual hard drives and a pre-installed copy of OS X Server for Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has dropped server from its lineup.

http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/10/16/apple-discontinues-mac-mini-server-limits-storage-options-with-latest-hardware-refresh